# Not able to get data with ImportXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the text from the body of the posting in CraigsList using the following formula in google Docs' spreadsheet, but keep an error message saying "The XPATH query did not return any data."

The formula I'm using is,

=ImportXML(D2,"//section[@id='postingbody']")

where D2 has the posting url: http://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/apa/3608091461.html

I looked at several references to check on my formula, but I cannot figure out what's wrong.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you in advanced! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Xpath` expression :

```
//*[@id="postingbody"]/text()
```

Comment: hmm, still didn't work for me.  I've tried replacing "section" with other "div" and corresponding id or class attributes, and seems to work just fine.  It's only when I introduce "section" when this seems to fail.  wondering if it's just not up-to-date with the introduction of "section" in html5...

Answer (score 0):

It could just be craigslist blocking it , there are really strict with their scraping rules.

you can try two things, you may need to play around with which part you want to extract or how you want to format it:

you can try: =REGEXEXTRACT(concatenate(IMPORTXML(A1,"//html")),".*avoiding scams(.*\n?.*) do NOT")

or try: =importxml(A1,"//html")

or lastly: =importxml(A1,"//body")